# GIFs aren't being transformed

Tags: image-transforms, gif

I know that others have had issues with transforms and GIFs, but I wanted to post a question as I am running pretty up-to-date versions of everything, which to my understand should mean transforming GIFs should work.

The server is running on PHP 7.0.7 and this is the ImageMagick set up:
[image]

Within the control panel, there is no preview for GIFs:

[image]

And when trying to transform the image on the template, it is being changed into a static image with only the first frame showing.

Is there another setting I need to look at changing?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`?  Does other (non-animated GIFs, PNGs, JPGs) images work as expected?

Comment: Yes, other formats were working as expected. I was also getting stuck image transform tasks all the time and [out of memory errors](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9kzrY.png). I have been talking to my host trying to resolve these, but to no avail. In over two years of building sites with Craft, I have yet to have a build were I am able to use ImageMagick. It just seems impossible to create an environment were it works.

Comment: Yeah... it can be a picky beast.  And not sure if this is what you're running into, but even on the bleeding edge Imagick has made breaking changes (again) that we're having to work through. https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine/pull/500

Comment: From your experience should a memory limit of 256MB be sufficient? Do the error messages mean anything to you? This is what my host said: _If by enabling ImageMagick on php7 its asking for more memory then there is very little we can do except upgrading to a cloud vps. However, if the application has anything along with that that is resource intensive, particularly memory and if there is a way to disable it for testing you may try it with your developer if that helps. If not you will really need to upgrade to a cloud vps._ Any ideas? I need to get GIFs working for this project...

Comment: 256MB should be plenty. If you want to send along some CP/FTP credentials to support@craftcms.com we can take a quick look, too.